# Default constructor with std::reference_wrapper as member?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, reference-wrapper

I have this struct:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(const Wrapper &wrapper, /*...*/) :
        wrapper(std::cref(wrapper)), /*...*/ {}

    std::reference_wrapper<Wrapper const> wrapper;
    /*...*/
};
```

However, now I want to use a `tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<MyStruct>`, which is not possible since `MyStruct` doesn't have a default constructor. But I don't know how to define it since `wrapper` must be initialized somehow. Is there any solution for this (apart from using raw pointers)?

`tbb` error (where `FindAffineShapeArgs` is `MyStruct` here):

```
/usr/include/tbb/concurrent_queue.h(453): error: no default constructor exists for class "FindAffineShapeArgs"
          T value;
            ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "void tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<T, A>::clear() [with T=FindAffineShapeArgs, A=tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>]" at line 446
            instantiation of "tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<T, A>::~concurrent_bounded_queue() [with T=FindAffineShapeArgs, A=tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>]" at line 272 of "/home/luca/Dropbox/HKUST/CloudCache/cloudcache/CloudCache/Descriptors/hesaff/pyramid.cpp"
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Can't you just delete your default constructor?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue`, but a casual reading of the documentation doesn't suggest that it would require its elements to be default-constructible. What makes you believe the lack of such a constructor would pose a problem?

Comment: If you want to have a reference you cannot be default constructable.  You can use a pointer but then you need to check for null values all over the place.  Pick you poison.

Comment: @Raxvan That would exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Look at my updated answer (using `icpc` as compiler). Did I misunderstood this error?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't have a default constructor

Comment: Just use a pointer.  KISS.  Stop banging your head against the wrapper.

Comment: I see. `tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue` seems to be rather poorly written, when something as innocuous as `clear()` inexplicably wants to default-construct an element.

Comment: @justHelloWorld _"I don't have a default constructor"_ Does that `tbb` stuff require you to provide one?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it seems so from my updated question

Comment: @IgorTandetnik An older version I found on the interwebs default-constructs an element per element in the queue :(

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Anyway, `concurrent_bounded_queue` says it's "similiar to `concurrent_queue`", whose [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506200) does call out that it requires default constructible elements. Still, badly organized.